# Error on adding expect method when implementing test API using supertest

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, supertest

I'm trying to test my users endpoint using supertest :

```
   router.post("/users", async (req, res) => {
  const user = new User(req.body);
  try {
    await user.save();
    const token = await user.generateAuthToken();
    res.status(201).send({ user: user, token: token });
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send(e);
  }
});
```

My user.test.js look like so :

```
  const request = require("supertest");
  const app = require("../src/app");

  test("Should signup a new user", async () => {
  await request(app)
    .post("/users")
    .send({
      name: "Andrew",
      email: "andrew@example.com",
      password: "MyPass777!",
    })
    .expect(201);
});
```

when i run this code i got this error :

[image]

But when i remove .expect(201) everything is working fine, can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

try using this instead:

```
  const {status} = await request(app)
    .post("/users")
    .send({
      name: "Andrew",
      email: "andrew@example.com",
      password: "MyPass777!",
    })
  
  expect(status).toBe(201);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have same problem. Tried

```
const {status} = await request(app)
    .post("/users")
    .send({
      name: "Andrew",
      email: "andrew@example.com",
      password: "MyPass777!",
    })
  
  expect(status).toBe(201)
```

didn't worked.
Also, tried

```
try {
 await request(app).post('/users').send({
     name: 'Andrew',
     email: 'andrew@example.com',
     password: 'MyPass777!'
 }).expect(201)
    }catch(e) {
          console.log(e)
 }
```

still getting 404 error but tests are passing in later case.My everything else is same as in the original question.